# What technology assistance did NASA give to hikers to the South Pole using renewables-only?

Tags: nasa, solar-power

The CBS News article [Expedition Antarctica: A father and son's journey to save the planet](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/expedition-antarctica-cbsn-originals/) says (in part):

> The success of the expedition necessitated the pioneering of new equipment that would use renewable energy to melt snow and ice into hot water on the move in the Antarctic. So, while Robert had previously used jet fuel to cook his food and keep warm in the -40-degree temperatures, this time he and his son used biofuels derived from wood chips to do the job. **They used solar panels, provided by NASA, that plugged into their sleds to melt ice and snow into drinkable water.**

**Question:** I'm curious about what technology assistance NASA gave to hikers to the South Pole. I'm guessing there's more than just "here's some solar panels and a roll of nichrome wire for a heater." Were batteries or other low temperature resistant electronics involved, or special insulation to keep the melt volume from refreezing? What (if any) parts of the assistant are a direct result of NASA's activities in space and/or inhospitable environments even on Earth in general?

[image: Antarctica hikers Barney and Robert Swan]

**above:** "Robert and Barney Swan towing sleds topped with solar panels across Antarctica." From [here](https://www.cbsnews.com/news/expedition-antarctica-cbsn-originals/). Credit: SHELL-Technical Partners

Comment: I'm wondering: since the conversion efficiency is of order 30%, wouldn't a more passive system, like a solar water heater have been more efficient for melting snow for drinking water?

Comment: We may calculate the electrical energy necessary to melt about 2 to 3 litres of water per person and day. A solar water heater with a parabolic mirror needs to be aligned to the sun, difficult when towing a sled. A water heater panel would need to circulate a heat transfer fluid between the panel and the snow/water container.

Comment: @Uwe no it doesn't. A solar water heater can be just a black box with a transparent window and some liquid running through some tubes. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solar_water_heating

Comment: Regarding efficiency: a thermal system would need some quality insulation against convective heat loss (i.e. a vacuum). Maybe a thin solar panel actually works out less than 30% the weight of an insulated thermal system?

Comment: @BlakeWalsh that's quite a lucid analysis, you've sold me! Yes, by converting to electricity first, the energy can be released back into a much smaller volume (the "melt chamber") with a correspondingly smaller surface area that does not require windows transparent to visible light, and is therefore much easier to effectively insulate. It also offers the further possibility of storage if batteries were used, or for charging other devices (GPS, phones, flashlights, cameras).

Comment: I find it ridiculous that they lugged those huge solar panels around just for melting ice when you could just as easily shove bottles into your jacket during moments of exertion to both prevent sweating and melt ice. I find it more plausible that they charged batteries which could be used to later power heaters when things reached -40.

Comment: @anon I think Robert Swan would find your proposal that he open his jacket in -80C weather and insert several kilograms of ice similarly ridiculous! https://youtu.be/zCUeX7XdzW0?t=64 it's almost as if he's addressing you directly ;-)

Comment: related: [How did O’Brady charge his electronic gear while hiking across Antarctica?](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/q/21362/12619)

Comment: I'm kind of wondering if NASA provided some highly-concentrated food as well, like the stuff they have on the ISS. That has to pack well when you need to pack light.